# Error in xj[i] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

```
Dong.part <- matrix(c(39100, 40900, 41000, 43900, 44100, 44300, 47200, 48800, 48000, 
49700, 49850, 47700, 48200, 45850, 44800, 44300, 43150, 43350, 
43550, 42800, 43200, 41550, 40900, 41250, 42000, 42550, 42400, 
42150, 43500, 42150, 40850, 39950, 41000, 41650, 41000, 41800, 
41700, 41300, 42400, 42200, 44550, 45300, 45450, 46200, 46300, 
46300, 46600, 47100, 46350, 46000, 45900, 47900, 50000, 52800, 
52100, 51700, 52300, 51600, 50100, 51100, 54000, 56400, 58200, 
57500, 59700, 60300, 59600, 60500, 61900, 61200, 62500, 62500, 
65100, 66400, 66000, 67800, 69200, 72200, 71000, 71100, 70500, 
65000, 65400, 60800, 60500, 63000, 62100, 62000, 64000, 64200, 
62500, 63200, 63200, 66900, 66400, 67000, 69900, 70200, 69900, 
71700, 73000, 76400, 74700, 74500, 73000, 75900, 79500, 84800, 
84500, 87400, 88500, 88300, 88200, 89800, 88000, 85200, 86300, 
81600, 76500, 82700, 82500, 82000, 80400, 81000, 80000, 76300, 
81800, 79300, 79400, 78200, 78900, 82000, 83000, 85200, 87000, 
86100, 84700, 86000, 84800, 86200, 88500, 89000, 89500, 88000, 
87800, 87000, 84200, 82500, 80200, 74000, 65200, 67800, 70800, 
70000, 73300, 76300, 76000, 73800, 67000, 64400, 63000, 62500, 
62500, 66800, 68800, 69000, 68700, 69300, 69400, 72000, 71700, 
69900, 71000, 70100, 68800, 69000, 68800, 67500, 68000, 68000, 
69800, 68900, 68800, 68700, 67500, 67900, 69800, 70200, 69600, 
69500, 68200, 68000, 67000, 67800, 66800, 68900, 68400, 68700, 
68900, 70500, 70400, 70500, 72800, 74100, 72500, 71500, 71900, 
72100, 69600, 69600, 68000, 66800, 66700, 66600, 66400, 65000, 
63000, 63400, 62100, 60300, 58100, 61200, 64800, 64800, 64900, 
63800, 63500, 61900, 62000, 61000, 62100, 61000, 60500, 60800, 
60400, 60000, 59100, 57900, 54200, 52700, 52100, 51600, 50200, 
51100, 50700, 47900, 48300, 48150, 51800, 54000, 52600, 53000, 
54500, 54000, 53000, 53100, 52700, 55800, 58300, 58100, 57600, 
56700, 57200, 58500, 59500, 62500, 62600, 62900, 62000, 61000, 
59500, 60300, 58000, 57000, 57000, 59000, 59200, 57700, 56700, 
54800, 57400, 58400, 57500, 57300, 58300, 57000, 56700, 55800, 
56100, 56400, 56000, 56500, 55800, 56500, 58800, 60000, 60400, 
60400, 62200, 69900, 70300), ncol=1)

dummy <- seq(0,0, length.out=nrow(Dong.part))

Dong.part <- cbind(Dong.part, dummy)


for(i in 100:nrow(Dong.part)){
if(Dong.part[i,1]<= min(Dong.part[i-99:i-1,1])){
Dong.part[i,4] <- 1
 }
 }
```

This is the stock price and dummy is what I made.
I want to compare the stock prices in every interval of length 99.

If the stock price (which is located in the first column) is the lowest in the interval whose length is 99, I want to change the dummy value to 1 at the row.

However, it does not work at all. How can I make this work well?

Comment: Study `help("Syntax")` to learn the order of operator precedence in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you forgot round parentheses around `i-99` and `i-1`; also the dummy is column 2 (there is no column 4):

```
for(i in 100:nrow(Dong.part)){
    if(Dong.part[i,1] <= min(Dong.part[(i-99):(i-1),1])){
        Dong.part[i,2] <- 1
    }
}
```